# Change Visibility of VBA Userform Combox Dropdown if Selection Contains Keyword

Tags: vba, excel

VBA Userform Combox dropdown if selection contains keyword "Director" I like `textbox1` to be visible.

So I have a userform and got textbox labelled mobile number but I don't need the textbox or label to show unless in combo box drop contains word Director code I tride to use but doesn't work is...

```
ComboBox3_Change ()     
If UCase(ComboBox3.text) = "OPERATION DIRECTOR" Then Textbox1.Visible = True
If UCase(ComboBox3.text) = "OPERATION DIRECTOR" Then Label26.Visible = True
```

Doesn't seem to work it doesn't unhide the textbox.

To hide textbox I used:

```
With Me
.Textbox1.Visible = False
.Label26.Visible = False
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you checking `ComboBox3.Text` in `Textbox1_Change`. I explaind last time how to get the `Textbox1_Change` event. Did you try that with the Combobox?

Comment: Sorry I should of put combobox3_Change () I put your code in there and change it to combobox3.text  <i/> If UCase(ComboBox3.text) = "OPERATION DIRECTOR" Then Textbox1.Visible = True </> doesnt seem to work like it did when I using a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an event over the combobox. To make sure VBA generates it automatically, simply double click on the `ComboBox`, when the form is in "developer"-mode. You will get something like this with the cursor in the middle:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

End Sub
```

Then this is probably the shortest way to do it in a 1-liner:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    tb1.Visible = CBool(UCase(ComboBox1) = "OD")
End Sub
```

It is translated to:

```
If Ucase(ComboBox1) = "OD" Then 
   tb1.Visible = True
End If
```

Comment: Out of interest is there a way of adding more than one word to be checked like looks for operation director and then IT Director performs same thing I did try it by adding another line but then they both stopped working

Comment: Write below the second line like this `tb1.Visible = CBool(UCase(ComboBox1) = "ITDirector")` or google "nested if vba" and implement it. Or "Select Case VBA".

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code in the combobox change event i.s.o. the textbox1 change event:

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    If UCase(ComboBox3.text) = "OPERATION DIRECTOR" Then Textbox1.Visible = True
    If UCase(ComboBox3.text) = "OPERATION DIRECTOR" Then Label26.Visible = True
end sub
```